# Visual webpart not displaying for anonymous users

Tags: anonymous-authentication, visual-web-part

I configured my SharePoint application to allow anonymous access and it's working fine.

When I add a visual web part that contains just a label to a page and approve it, anonymous users can't see the webpart.

Is there anything that I have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my webpart zone was inside the security-trimming control, after i delete this control my web part works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Any change that you enabled the output cache on your page? It behaves different for anonymous users vs logged in users.

p.s. just a wild guess, but the output cache monster got me a few times ;)